# R: Adding qualitative data using a text() argument to a for loop: unknown index type 'list' error message

Tags: r, list, for-loop, plot

I have sample data which is stored in a 
`data.frame xy` and which is plotted in for loop like in the code below. This works all correctly.

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME3","NAME3"),ID=c(87,87,87,199,199,199,233,233), X_START_YEAR=c(1950,1988,1994,1899,1909,1924,1945,1948),Y_START_VALUE=c(75,25,-90,-8,-55,-10,-9,12),X_END_YEAR=c(1985,1994,1999,1904,1924,1987,1946,1949), Y_END_VALUE=c(20,50,-15,-70,-80,-100,24,59))

   NAME  ID X_START_YEAR Y_START_VALUE X_END_YEAR Y_END_VALUE
1 NAME1  87         1950            75       1985          20
2 NAME1  87         1988            25       1994          50
3 NAME1  87         1994           -90       1999         -15
4 NAME2 199         1899            -8       1904         -70
5 NAME2 199         1909           -55       1924         -80
6 NAME2 199         1924           -10       1987        -100
7 NAME3 233         1945            -9       1946          24
8 NAME3 233         1948            12       1949          59
```

Now I am trying to incorporate qualitative data which is stored in a `data.frame data_qual` and I am trying to include this in a second for loop (as in the code below the part that is commented out). But I am running into the error: `error in ind[i]: unknown index type 'list'`

```
data_qual <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME2","NAME3"),ID=c(199,233),X_START_YEAR=c(1986,1905), Y_START_VALUE=c("-X","ST"),X_END_YEAR=c(1987,1907),Y_END_VALUE=c("-X","ST"))

  NAME  ID  X_START_YEAR Y_START_VALUE X_END_YEAR Y_END_VALUE
1 NAME2 199         1986            -X       1987          -X
2 NAME3 233         1905            ST       1907          ST
```

What I am trying to do is to place the qualitative values using a `text()` argument to place it at its `X_END_YEAR` position and slightly above the x axis.

What could be wrong about my approach so that I get an error message as indicated above? Does anyone have an idea how I could fix it? Any help is kindly appreciated. The code with the sample data should work when you exclude the second `for loop` (the part that is commented out) but like this doesn't include the qualitative data.

```
# split xy by group as defined by ID
ind <- split(xy,xy$ID)

for (i in ind){
  xx = unlist(i[,grep('X_',colnames(i))])
  yy = unlist(i[,grep('Y_',colnames(i))])    
  fname <- paste0(i[1, 'ID'], '.png')
  png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
  if(any(xx < 1946)) {my_x_lim <- c(min(xx), 2014)} else {my_x_lim <- c(1946, 2014)} 
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(xx, 
       yy,
       main=unique(i[,1]),
       xlab="Time [Years]",
       ylab="Value [m]",
       pch=21, bg='white',
       xlim = my_x_lim,font.lab=2, cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1.1)
  axis(1, at = seq(1000, 2050, 5), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3)
  axis(2, at = seq(-100000, 100000, 500), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3)
  abline(h=0, col = "gray60")
  i <- i[,-1]
  segments(i[,2],i[,3],i[,4],i[,5],lwd=2)
  points(xx, yy, pch=21, bg='white', cex=0.7)
  title(sub=i$warn, adj=0.035, line=-1.5, font=3, cex=1)

  if (i$ID[1] %in% data_qual%ID){
    rel_data_qual <- data_qual[data_qual$ID %in% i$ID,]
    text(x = rel_data_qual$X_END_YEAR,
         y = min(i$Y_END_VALUE + 3),
         labels = rel_data_qual$Y_END_VALUE)  
  }  
      dev.off()
    }
```

Comment: You have asked a lot of questions over the past couple of weeks concerning these data. Quite a few times, you have made simple mistakes which I believe you would have resolved on your own. If you don't think you could have solved these problems on your own, then consider spending more time learning the R basics before asking others for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `i` to index, because `i` is a `data.frame`. You can continue using `i` directly, as you did in the outer `for`. I think you were trying to do something like this:

```
for(j in 1:length(which(data_qual$ID %in% i$ID))) {
  text(
         x = data_qual[data_qual$ID %in% i$ID, 'X_END_YEAR'] [j],
         y = min(i$Y_END_VALUE+3),
    labels = data_qual[data_qual$ID %in% i$ID, 'Y_END_VALUE'] [j]
  )
}
```

But even that is adding an unnecessary `for` loop. You could just say:

```
rel_data_qual <- data_qual[data_qual$ID %in% i$ID,]
text(x = rel_data_qual$X_END_YEAR,
     y = min(i$Y_END_VALUE + 3),
     labels = rel_data_qual$Y_END_VALUE)
```

Because `text` is vectorized, meaning (loosely) that it can accept vectors of arguments, rather than one at a time.

Comment: thank you for your answer @nograpes. I have a problem though, in my data not in every group of `xy` (defined by `ID`) qualitative data is present! I changed my input data in order make it clearer by adding a new group to xy -> `NAME3` with `ID` 233. This results in an empty data.frame and an additional error that `length for labels is 0`. How could I get rid of this error?

Comment: I find your lack of effort confusing. You clearly understand the problem, and your code indicates that you have the tools to solve it -- just write an if statement to check before your run `text`.